# svn command to show file revisions while getting differences between two tags

Tags: svn, batch-file, diff, revision

I want the differences between two tags lets say `HEAD` and `UAT_1`.

The command `svn diff URL1 URL2` would give all the file differences but the revision number that it gets for each file would be the revision of the directory.

Is there any way that I can get the latest revision number of the file that is shown as difference that is in the repository and not the directory revision.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`svn info [TARGET]` (with full path to file): *Last Changed Rev* string

```
svn info
Print information about each TARGET
```

You have to get only list of TARGETS (from `sv diff`)

Comment: This would certainly take a lot of time. For instance lets say each svn command you run takes 1sec. If you get 100 differences (targets) using svn diff which takes only one command to run; that would be 1 sec. Now if you run svn info for each of those 100 differences the time taken would be 100*1 seconds. So the total time to get I want is 110 sec. I want something that can get this in one command only.